# C++ 17 friend function declaration and inline namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, c++17, friend-function

Consider the following program

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N1
{
    inline namespace N2
    {
        class A
        {
        public:
            friend void f( const A & );
        private:
            int x = 10;
        };

        //void f( const A & );
    }

    void N2::f( const A &a ) { std::cout << a.x << '\n'; }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace N1;

    A a;

    f( a );
}
```

According to the C++ 17 Standard (10.3.1.2 Namespace member definitions)

> 3 If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template97 the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not
>   by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (6.4.1) or
>   qualified lookup (6.4.3).

So the name of the friend function is invisible in the namespace N2. So it also should be invisible in the namespace N1.

However the code is compiled and executed without warnings by the **clang HEAD 10.0.0**.

The compiler **gcc HEAD 10.0.0 20191** issues warnings

```
prog.cc:18:10: warning: 'void N1::N2::f(const N1::N2::A&)' has not been declared within 'N1::N2'
   18 |     void N2::f( const A &a ) { std::cout << a.x << '\n'; }
      |          ^~
prog.cc:10:25: note: only here as a 'friend'
   10 |             friend void f( const A & );
      |                         ^
```

but runs the program and the correct result is outputted.

Visual C++ 2019 also compiles the code successfully without warnings and the program outputs the expected result.

Is there a bug of the three compilers because the name `f` is invisible so the definition of the friend function `f` in the enclosing namespace is incorrect?

Comment: How it is invisible? You clearly defined it and so it is visible.

Comment: @ÖöTiib See the quote from the C++ Standard.

Comment: Where  does it say that definition of function turns invisible?

Comment: @ÖöTiib What function?! The name f is invisible in the namespace N2.

Comment: Despite N2::f is clearly defined in posted code?

Comment: GCC does generate a hard error when you use `-pedantic-errors`, so it seems to assume the code is ill-formed according to the standard. And the error is on the definition, so the body of `main` isn't really relevant. And neither is the `inline`. All compilers behave the same without it.

Comment: @ÖöTiib One more. The name f is invisible in the namespace N2. So how the function can be defined in the enclosing namespace N1 if the qualified name look-up does not find the function?

Comment: Paragraph 2 seems very relevant also.

Comment: @aschepler So the two paragraphs make a confusing.

Comment: "A function ﬁrst declared in a friend declaration has the linkage of the namespace of which it is a member. " So function can be first declared by friend declaration and so out of line definition matches it and can't complain there are no declarations is valid and makes it visible.

Comment: @ÖöTiib It would be correct if the function would be declared also outside the class definition in the namespace N2.

Comment: So are you claiming that the definition of N1::N2::f is illegal?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I think so. Also take into account that the compilers behave differently.

Comment: To me it is previous declaration and where it is said that definition should do lookups?

Comment: @ÖöTiib Because there is used a qualified name that was declared in other namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the function bodies and the parameter of `f` are not really relevant since the issue is only with the name lookup of `N2::f`. After removing them, it also doesn't matter whether the namespace `N2` is `inline` or not. All compilers behave the same way in either case.

GCC warns, but gives a hard error with `-pedantic-errors` on the definition of `N2::f`. MSVC and Clang always accept the code without diagnostic.

I think you are right, that going by the wording `N2::f` in the function definition declarator should be looked up by qualified name lookup rules, which should not find the `friend` declaration without an intervening declaration of `f` at `N2`'s scope, not using a qualified name.

However there is [defect report 1477](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1477) which seems to have had the intention of making such an out-of-namespace definition well-formed.

In the open [CWG issue 1900](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1900) this question is reposed and the issue description also concludes that the normative text of the standard does not allow the definition. It also notes that there is implementation variance, as you are observing.

For Clang, there is a bug report about a similar case [here](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40233).

Comment: It does matter that the namespace is inline because otherwise the unqualified name A will not be found in the demonstrative program.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes you are right. I think I removed the contents of the function bodies and the parameter and forgot about it. The point is that the compilers behave the same in regards to the name lookup for `N2::f`, no matter whether the namespace is inline.